# How to add a number to the name of an item that already exists in a json object before adding it to the object

Tags: javascript, node.js

Basically, I have an JSON Object named map, to which I add a key and value whenever it is needed for temporary storage.
So I need a function that checks if the key already exists in map and if it does exist then it adds a number to end of the key's name like _(number) and the number increases for every duplicate.

i.e (Just an example, I'm using the map for different purposes)

```json
{
   "hello": "world",
   "hello_(1)": "do you like pizza?",
   "hello_(2)": "https://google.com/"
}
```

Please do help me, Thanks!

Comment: what you have tried so far.

Comment: Why not just use an array?

Comment: **JSON** and **object** are two different things. There is no **JSON Object**

Comment: _Please specify which part of this you need help with._  JSON is a beautiful place to cut the scope of this problem in half.  You either have a problem parsing your JSON into a JavaScript object, then serializing it back to JSON.  *or* you have a problem modifying the object or checking to see if it has keys.   Furthermore, you can cut the problem in half again by telling us if you need to know how to check if a key exists, *or* if you need to know how to generate a key with an incremented number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use [Map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map).

### (almost) One liner

Here is a short snippet:

```
var myMap = new Map();
myMap.has("hello") ? myMap.get("hello").push("newValueForHello") : myMap.set("hello", ["newValueForHello"])
```

### Multi lines

The above is not very readable so I'll also add a more readable snippet but does the exact same thing

```
// Create the map instance
var myMap = new Map();

// if the map instance already has a "hello" key
if(myMap.has("hello") {
  // get the key (which must be an array) and push the new value to the array.
  myMap.get("hello").push("newValueForhello")
} else {
  // if the map doesn't have the "hello" key, the add an empty array.
  myMap.set("hello", ["newValueForHello"])
}
```

### As a function

Here it is as a function..

```
function addItemToMap(mapObj, key, value) {
  // if the key doesn't exist yet..
  if(!mapObj.has(key)) {
    // initialize it to an empty array.
    mapObj.set(key, [])
  }
  
  // At this point the key must exist, and it must be an array, so just push a new item to the array.
  mapObj.get(key).push(value)
}

// usage 
var myMap = new Map()
addItemToMap(myMap, "hello", "first hello item")
addItemToMap(myMap, "hello", "second hello item")
```

Comment: absolutely right @CherryDT

Comment: your solution is not working.   'mapObj.get(key).push(value)' is not a correct syntax, are you trying to mutate immutable Map structure or am I missing sth?

Comment: @Moonjsit , Note that the function requires the first param to be a Map object. And the function sets the value of the key to be an array. So I just push more items to an array. I'm not making changes to the Map key. I added a usage section that might explain how to use the function.

Comment: I see, so basically you are setting Map keys values indirectly - mutating the key value. I believe you should do mapObj.set(key, [...mapObj.get(key), value]) and the initial value should be a map, not a collections as question states. Additional the function has side effects - it is actually updating the passed argument - that's a bad practice.

Comment: @Moonjsit You are right that this doesn't really answer the OP question, but as you stated in your answer doing what the OP asked for is not easy to maintain and can be considered as "bad practice". So I just suggested a different approach. About the side effects - I'm not sure that this can be considered a "side effect" I'm not changing value of some external field. The caller of the function has full control over what is going into the function and what comes out. Thanks for your comments! Made me think.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution to your question:

```js
const myDictionary = {
    "hello": "hello",
    "bye": "bye"
}

const addItemToDictionary = (newKey, newVal, dict) => {
    const keyRegExp = new RegExp(`^${newKey}\.*`)
    const keyCount = Object.keys(dict).filter(key => keyRegExp.test(key)).length;
    return ({
        ...dict,
        [`${newKey}_(${keyCount})`]: newVal
    })
}

console.log(
    addItemToDictionary('hello', 'hello yet again',
        addItemToDictionary('bye', 'bye again',
            addItemToDictionary('hello', 'hello again', myDictionary)
        )
    )
);
```

Bare in mind there is a lot of edge cases that you can have, eg. your new key can be 'hell' and it will break this solution (this is just one of many).

In such a situations  as an engineer you should rethink your approach.

I would suggest instead of adding new elements to json as you asked you can simply change data structure interface:

```js
const myDictionary = {
    "hello": "hello",
    "bye": "bye"
}

const addItemToDictionary = (newKey, newVal, dict) => {
    const dictEntry = Object.keys(dict).find(key => key === newKey);
    return ({
        ...dict,
        [newKey]: dictEntry ? [...[dictEntry], newVal] : newVal
    })

}


console.log(
    addItemToDictionary('hello', 'hello yet again',
        addItemToDictionary('bye', 'bye again',
            addItemToDictionary('hello', 'hello again', myDictionary)
        )
    )
);
```